# open multiple websites in selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium

Is possible to create a list of web pages and open this list with python loop script?
I trying something like this but after first site fail and selenium say:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Session [1e42078b-f999-4a16-9b36-0c7281c95d44] was terminated due to CLIENT_STOPPED_SESSION' ; Stacktrace:
```

And here is my small script

```
from selenium import webdriver

fox = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities={
            "browserName": "phantomjs",
            "platform": "LINUX",
        })

sites = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com']

for s in sites:
    adrs = "http://" + str(s)
    fox.get(adrs)
    snap = s.split('.')[0]
    fox.save_screenshot(snap +'.png')
    fox.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fox.quit()` call should not happen in the loop, it should be called after:

```
for s in sites:
    adrs = "http://" + str(s)
    fox.get(adrs)
    snap = s.split('.')[0]
    fox.save_screenshot(snap +'.png')
fox.quit()
```